# Always Sync Form Library Columns data with SQL Server 2008

Tags: 2007, sql-server

How do I set a "always-sync" connection between a Form Library and a Database (in SQL server 2008)?

Scenario:
I have a Form library that use InfoPath form. In the form library, there are multiple columns (or fields) and contain data. I also have a database inside SQL Server 2008. So, the question is how can I set in such a way that any data changes to form library will be reflect in the database and vice-versa. (Meaning that data in the form library will always be the same as the data in the database.)

For info: using MOSS 2007, SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that it is not possible to perform a "always-sync" connection between a form library and a database (in SQL Server 2008).

The only other way is using the SQL Server Replication provided you know the Form Library table located in the SQL server and then perform a replication between that table to another table in the SQL server.